# Unity 3d Nav Mesh Agent cannot get up steps at walking pace

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the Standard Assets "AIThirdPersonController" prefab with a script that set the destination depending on where you click on the scene. It uses a Nave Mesh Agent.

I am using a bunch of assets from Standard Assets prototyping. Stairs and Ramp.

The problem is that the character will climb stairs if the speed is set to 1, which is running. But I want it to climb stairs when its a walk (0.5).

The character gets to the stairs and stops, the animation continues the walking animation, but he does not get up the stairs. The step height for humanoid is set to 0.4, and the stairs are less than that (they are .25).

Does not have any problem getting up ramps.

Anyone know how to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but gonna give my answer here anyways.

I had the same problem and fixed moving the Capsule Collider in the agent up a little bit.

I changed the offset in the y axis from 1 to 1.25. Now there is no collision at all on the agent foot. This change didn't have any negative impact in my game, but is better to test this approach carefully.

I figure it has something to do with the friction between the colliders since when the agent has a higher speed it has no problem.

If anyone has a better fix, please let me know.